How can i check whether the user has submitted file in the file input form in html when the user submits the form?
This is the app.post method in the index.js file which will receive the filename and I want to check if the image exists then the image name will be added to the file else it will not.
app.post('/addPost', upload.single('blogImage'), (req, res) => {

    //for the written content
    let data = req.body;
    data.blogImageName = req.file.filename;
    console.log(data);
    postContent(req.body);


});

This is the html form
<form action="/addPost" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="createPostForm">

      <div>
        <label for="AddImage">Add Image for the blog : </label>
        <input type="file" name="blogImage" ><br>
      </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Post">


  </form>

if i submit the form without uploading file then it gives an error.
How can i check if filename exists in the request?

did you want to check on the server or in the client, it's not clear from your question

To upload a file you need multer or express-fileupload package. Do you only want to know how to check if user submitted file or you want to know the entire process about how to check and upload file as well?Please specify

I wanted to check on the server side @JaromandaX

I have imported the multer package. I want to check at the server side if the user has submitted image or not. @Subha

@VedicaGairola, I have posted my detailed answer with explaination.Please chcek and let me know your feedback.

File exists: Just want to clarify. File may be already existing in the server as it has been already uploaded by some one. What would be the action to take in that case. The other point is clear from the OP is that the user should have uploaded a file prior to start uploading into the server. This has two points to do. A frontend validation as well as a backend validation, both are possible in this case. How would you see these points.

Well ,When you upload files with multer the uploaded file data is not stored directly in req.body, rather multer attach file-data into request.file(for single file) & request.files(for multiple/arrays of file).
request.body contains onlye the text-fields.
So try this code in place of your existing code.
app.post('/addPost', upload.single('blogImage'), (req, res) => {

    let fileData = req.file ;

    if(!fileData)  //return `true` in case file is not submitted
    {
    ..... //you can redirect user or whatever you want
    }
    .....
    //you can do rest of the work regarding file-upload

});

For more information on multer you can visit the link below.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

add validation
if (!req.file) { throw new Error("File is required"); }
return true;

